# How is installing from a repository different from installing via downloading a .deb file?

Tags: package-management, repository

I am new to Ubuntu. How is installing software from a repository different from downloading the .deb file from a website and installing through the package manager?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the other answers are correct, you get:

- Auto Updates
- Dependencies

But most importantly, you get **reliability.** Repositories systems in place to make sure that the software you download will work on your computer. In windows when you want to install an application to fix a problem, you have to trust not only the website that's hosting it, but [all the computers in between](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_in_the_middle_attack).

**With key signing, you can be sure that you are installing software that the developers intended for you to install.**

That just leaves the issues to you, to make sure that you chose good developers.

Comment: Thank you, so repositories (1) keep software updated, (2) ensures that you have dependencies, (3) are reliable due to key signing.

Comment: Exactly. Though to be specific, the tool (apt-get) handles updates and dependences. The repository itself is just the location you can go to download.

Answer (score 2):

Downloading from a repo with `apt-get install` will also make sure all of the dependencies are installed.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, when you install an application from a .deb file, you won't get package updates like you do when you install from a repository.

Answer (score 2):

The repository will keep you sofware up-to-date and install the dependencies as well. The .deb file don't do that, but it is portable.